# Using Object instead of generics

Tags: c#, generics, object

If I'm using non-generic collections, functions and so on then passed value types will be boxed because of casting to `Object` (that is not good for performance). But after including generics in C# 2.0 most situations of passing value type as `Object` was obviated.

Are there still any situations in **competent** programming where it's not possible to accomplish something with generics and still need to use casting to `Object`? If so can you please show an example? Thanks.

Comment: It's worth noting that boxing still occurs for value types in many scenarios, even with generics.  The performance hit you take from that is so negligible in most cases that it's really not a cause for concern.

Comment: @Dan Puzey, in 1 line of code - yes. But put this line to the loop that runs few thousand times and you will see how its negligible...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of `System.Object` offers flexibility (at the cost of performance).

Consider the storage mechanisms of ASP.NET (Session and Application), they have the general structure of

```
 Dictionary<string, object> PropertyBag;
```

And you would use them like

```
PropertyBag["currentCustomer"] = aCustmer;
PropertyBag["visits"] = 0;
```

It's not possible to replace `object` with something stronger typed here.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there still any situations in competent programming where it's not possible to accomplish something with generics and still need to use casting to Object

Of course there are. For example situations in which you don't know the type at compile time and you need to use reflection. But if you know the type at compile time strong typing with generics is preferable.